# PHP jQuery update rows of a table when the value of input change

Tags: php, jquery, html-table

First of all I need to say that I'm new to jQuery.

When I select an option of a menu, a PHP file is loaded into a div with the method load of jQuery. In this PHP file I have a table and a input text. When the PHP file is loaded it catch the values of database.

The problem apears that I need to create a search method for the values of database.

I need that when the user writes in the input of php document, the table load the values that match with the value of input.

The code that loads the PHP file is the next:

```
$("#searchuser").click(function() {
                $(".info").load("usuerlist.php",function(){
                    $("#search").keyup(function(){
                        alert($('#search').val());

                    });
                });
            });
```

The name search is the name of the input.
The code of PHP file is the next:

```
<?php 
require_once "aplicacio/loaddata.php";
include_once 'classe/gestorclass.php';

$var = new loaddata();
$var1 = $var->selectAllGestor();
$var2 = $var->selectAllUser();

?>
<div class="informacio">

Usuari<input type="text" name="cerca" id="cerca">
    <table class="infoTable">
    <tr class="titol"><td>User Name</td></tr>
    <?php
        for($i = 0; $i<sizeof($var1); $i++){
            if($i % 2){
                $res = '1';
            }else{
                $res= '2';
            }
            echo '<tr class="linia'.$res.'"><td>'.$var1[$i]->getUsuari().'</td></tr>';

        }
        ?>

</table>


</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand.  Are you trying to load a php file that is passed a variable from your input field that it uses to return data you need to insert into your original page?

Comment: The php file is load good into a div when I select the option in the menu. When the php file is loaded it's catch the values of databse an writes the in the table. Later, i desire that when I modify the value of the input the values of the table are update. For exemple if i write 'a' only appear the values users that have 'a' in the name.

Comment: I see, so you are not trying to actually change the values, just hide anything that doesn't match?  Filtering the results?

Comment: hide the things that not match is a possible solution. But if is posible I desire to filter the name values that match the input value.

Comment: Where are the name values displayed?  What variable is that?  Is it the `$var1[$i]->getUsuari()`?

Comment: yes, the '$var1[$i]->getUsuari()' displays the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
I create a file that genereates the table, and when I put info into the input I call this file with the next code:

```
$("#searchuser").click(function() {

$(".info").load("usuarislist.php",function(){
                    $("#cerca").keyup(function(){
                        var valor = $('#cerca').val();
                        $("#tableUser").load("aplicacio/tableGenerator.php?origen=tableUser&valor="+valor);
```

Comment: I was going to suggest something similar, just using `.ajax` instead of `.load`.